# Is this lock management code snippet unnecessarily complicated?

Tags: java, locking, fortify

The Hewlett Packard Enterprise application Fortify On Demand contains this code snippet titled "Example 2: The following code will always release the lock."

```
ReentrantLock  myLock = new ReentrantLock();

try {
    myLock.lock();
    performOperationInCriticalSection();
    myLock.unlock();
}
finally {
    if (myLock != null) {
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Why there is the last line in the `try` block to unlock the lock, when it is already handled in `finally`? Is it really necessary, or is it just part of some verbose coding standard? The `if` looks unnecessary too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code [throws an `IllegalMonitorStateException`](http://ideone.com/vtQonC), because it calls `unlock()` twice in succession.

From [`ReentrantLock.unlock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock--):

> **Throws:**
>
> `IllegalMonitorStateException` - if the current thread does not hold this lock

I would have to say that the code is incorrect, and I can't really guess at what they were trying to do. It could work if there was a `myLock = null;` immediately after the `unlock()` inside the `try` block, but doing that is still sloppy code. If `unlock()` throws an exception, then the second invocation of `unlock()` will throw another exception too.

The correct idiom is like this, according to the documentation for e.g. [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

```
Lock l = ...;
l.lock();
try {
    // access the resource protected by this lock
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}
```

If you want to be really safe, you could use *try-with-resources* to take advantage of the fact that if `close()` throws an exception while an exception from the `try` block is being thrown, the `close()` exception is added to the suppressed exceptions so neither of them is lost. (In both the preceding example and the HP example, if `unlock()` throws an exception, the exception being thrown from the `try` block is entirely lost.)

```
class Locker implements AutoCloseable {
    private final Lock lock;
    Locker(Lock lock) { this.lock = Objects.requireNonNull(lock);
                        this.lock.lock(); }
    @Override public void close() { lock.unlock(); }
}

Lock lock = ...;
try (Locker locker = new Locker(lock)) {
    // If both modifySharedState() and unlock()
    // throw an exception, the unlock() exception
    // is added to the modifySharedState()
    // exception's suppressed list.
    modifySharedState();
}
```

([Here's an example output using that code on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/f0zkYk))

Or you could write something like the code [which *try-with-resources* translates to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1):

```
Lock lock = ...;
lock.lock();
Throwable primary = null;
try {
    modifySharedState();
} catch (Throwable x) {
    primary = x;
    throw x;
} finally {
    try {
        lock.unlock();
    } catch (Throwable x) {
        if (primary != null) {
            primary.addSuppressed(x);
            // primary is already "in-flight"
            // so no need to throw it again
        } else {
            throw x;
        }
    }
}
```

That's a bit hard to follow, though.

Accounting for `unlock()` throwing an exception could make sense if the logic is more complicated than just `lock()...unlock()`, for example if you had more than one lock or the `unlock()` was conditional for some reason.